# How should one interpret the Normal/Gaussian Distribution function?

Tags: statistics, notation, normal-distribution, linear-regression, gaussian

While studying linear regression, my text book indicates that we account for noise, which is given by the function:

$$ \varepsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\beta^{-1}).$$

I know this is a normal distribution and I know through research that noise and error rates usually follow this distribution. However, I am puzzled by how I should interpret this, given that the normal distribution function is represented by:

$$ \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2).$$

What I do not understand, is what is the significance of the parameters used here? Namely $0$ and $\beta^{-1}$? Should I care about these or is this just standard notation? Does this simply mean that the mean is 0 and the standard deviation is a beta function?

Comment: $\mathcal{N}(0,\beta^{-1})$ is a normal distribution with mean zero and and variance $\beta^{-1}$.  The standard deviation of this distribution is $\sqrt{1/\beta}$.

Comment: $\beta$ here is the [*precision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(statistics)) i.e the reciprocal of the variance.  There is nothing significant about the use of $\beta$, and $\tau$ or $p$ are often used

Comment: Noise is defined to have mean $0$.  If it had nonzero expectation, we wouldn't think of it as 'noise' or 'error' - it would be a consistent bias.